# Is there a typetrait checking inclusion between types?

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, c++03

I'm looking for a typetrait able to know if the range of a type is included in another. A typetrait where `is_included_in<T,U>::value` is `true` when each value of type `T` can be stored as a value of type `U`. Example :

```
is_included_in<float,double>::value; // true
is_included_in<double,float>::value; // false
is_included_in<int,double>::value; // true
is_included_in<bool,long int>::value; // true
is_included_in<long long int,float>::value; // false
```

Is there somthing in Boost able to do this ? Or have I to write it myself ?

*Note: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reason.*

Comment: You might be able to cobble together something based on `std::numeric_limits`. Should be fairly easy to use it to derive the rules for comparing two integer or two floating point types. The tricky part would be to work around the rules between an integer and a floating point type.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [`std::numeric_limits::digits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) can help here to find out the size of a mantisa.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Why not when I have less than 5 relevant tags. The tag c++03 is followed by only 69 watchers. But in my experience, it's not enough to avoid C++11 solutions without an explicit note. Sometimes, I even had to justify why...

Comment: People shouldn't be questioning the frame of your question if it's specifically tagged [tag:c++03] (or [tag:c++98] which is basically the same thing). That's the reason we have the tag, after all!

Comment: I wasn't thinking about reaching those 69 watchers as much as constraining the question better. I know the search engine here leverages tags. It might even show relevant questions better. Also, it's good to be as specific as possible, and IMO language revision tags are an important part of it.

Comment: Indeed. I don't follow [tag:c++03], but I do follow [tag:c++], and when examining any question posted with [tag:c++], I'll be sure to look for further constraining tags. My point is I doubt I'm the only one working SO this way! Note that this is also why you should be sure to always use [tag:c++] first and foremost - I see a lot of questions missing that when there is [tag:c++11] or [tag:c++14] or [tag:c++17] or [tag:c++20] and will always edit it in. In conclusion, you did the right thing, carry on!

Comment: Points for your point of view. I will try to always add this tag. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'd have to make it yourself.

That being said, if you want to use this to make arithmetic conversions value-safe, Boost already has [`numeric_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html) that achieves this.

So, depending on your goal, you may not need a trait.

At the very least you could probably examine the `numeric_cast` implementation and use its principles to build your own trait(s).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. From Boost docs: _numeric_cast returns the result of converting a value of type Source to a value of type Target._ Therefore, it merely checks whether a single value can be "safely" casted. However, OP cares about _all possible values_ of a source type. Is it possible with `numeric_cast`?

Comment: @DanielLangr My point is that if the OP wants to use such a hypothetical trait as part of a solution that's like `numeric_cast`, then they can use `numeric_cast`. And, otherwise, they can use the implementation of `numeric_cast` (which must surely at least contain the logic they're asking about) to create the hypothetical trait. And otherwise the answer is "no". I feel I covered all those bases...

Answer (score 1):

For fundamental integral and floating-point types, you can compare their *number of digits* as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename U>  
struct is_included_in
  : boost::integral_constant<bool,
      std::numeric_limits<T>::digits <= std::numeric_limits<U>::digits> { };
```

It works for all you exemplary cases. The only problem is that it yields `true` for, e.g., `<float, long>`. A partial specialization helps here:

```
template <typename T, typename U,
  bool = boost::is_floating_point<T>::value && boost::is_integral<U>::value>
struct is_included_in
  : boost::integral_constant<bool,
      std::numeric_limits<T>::digits <= std::numeric_limits<U>::digits> { };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_included_in<T, U, true> : boost::false_type { };
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/NBXFOUK8fX9sxyfm.

Comment: A simple check for that would be to add a check for eg.: ``is_integral<T>::value == is_integral<U>::value`` or ``is_floating_point<T>::value == is_floating_point<U>::value`` in the condition. Both traits can be created by hand if they are not available.

Comment: @LuisMachuca I don't understand what for would be such checks useful.

Comment: For preventing "inclusion" between floating point types and integral types, where their ranges and granularity are not really comparable (where are you going to place ``-3154.901107`` in a ``long``'s range?).

Comment: @LuisMachuca Your checks does not cover cases where `T` is integral and `U` is floating point. You would neet 3 positive comparisons instead of 1 "negative" in my solution.